# Package to Interact with the turtlebot Simulator in Gazebo.''

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, turtlebot, turtlebot-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to create a package to Interact with the turtlebot Simulator in Gazebo using software outside,

What features I can use to interact with the simulation and turtlebot gazebo, have pretension to create a program to send and receive information from the simulation. So I would have a light on which way to publish and receive by an external software.

I can help xDDD

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194630/package-to-interact-with-the-turtlebot-simulator-in-gazebo.%27%27/) by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-10-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-10-09**:
Do you have the source code of the external software?

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-10-10**:
The external code, still do, but would like to know which methods I can use to communicate with the ROS / turtlebot / Gazebo, an example would be to have a method to create publisher and subscriber out through that code, I wonder as if I do this and how it would be!

thank;;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All you need is to follow this tutorial which explains in a very simple way how to write a c++ code to publish/subscribe to ros topics code and compile it with gcc linking to the roscpp library.
http://jbohren.com/articles/roscpp-hello-world/

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-10-12**:
Thank Mehdi, follow no doubt your help, but do not want to just make a publisher / subscribe to communicate with Turtlebot / gazebo, desire to make a program that from it we can send commands to the turtlebot the gazebo.

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-10-12**:
an example of what I want to do clear that the simplest way would be what matlab does with this tool: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/44853-use-matlab-ros-i-o-package-to-interact-with-the-turtlebot-simulator-in-gazebo

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-10-12**:
I create a program so that we can interact with it to the gazebo and turtlebot first and then with the real robot, know I have to publish through the publisher and subscribe more I wonder if it would be possible to incorporate my software to make direct it exactly like that Matlab package.

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-10-12**:
and which path I should follow to incorporate this direct communication of my software and receiving.I thank you very much your help! and the time it is devoting myself to answer my debts!

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-10-12**:
Well all interaction in ROS is based on publish/subscribe so I am pretty sure you can do whatever you want with that !! Controlling Turtlebot means publishing a command velocity message to the robot's topic responsible for that. And you are not limited to roscpp as library.

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-10-13**:
Exactly, I will follow the tutorial that you pointed me to start understanding the part of how I do to create the functions that go to communicate and receive the ROS. I really appreciate your attention, if you are able to send me a contact to exchange an idea more specific about my work,

**Comment by [leobber](https://answers.ros.org/users/20424/leobber/) on 2014-10-13**:
can be email, whatsapp.

Thank you so much.